How take Proxy apache
I'm trying to configure my Apache with a Java API to receive calls from my front end. The way below he receives the first call, I can log in, but the next calls I get 401 Unauthorized.
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.com.br
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com.br

    # Configuração para permitir solicitações de qualquer origem (CORS)
    # Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

    SSLEngine on

    # Configuração do proxy para encaminhar solicitações para a API Java em execução na porta 8082
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8082/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8082/

    #testes proxy
    ProxyPass / https://cliente.mydomain.com.br
    ProxyPassReverse / https://cliente.mydomain.com.br
    ## teste proxy
    ProxyPass "/api" "http://api.mydomain.com.br"
    ProxyPassReverse "/api" "http://api.mydomain.com.br"

    ProxyPass / http://cliente.mydomain.com.br
    ProxyPassReverse / http://cliente.mydomain.com.br


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mydomain.com.br/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mydomain.com.br/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
# Configuração para porta 80 (HTTP)
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com.br
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com.br

    # Configuração para permitir solicitações de qualquer origem (CORS)
    # Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

    # Redirecionamento para HTTPS
    Redirect permanent / https://api.mydomain.com.br/

    #testes proxy
    ProxyPass / https://cliente.mydomain.com.br
    ProxyPassReverse / https://cliente.mydomain.com.br
    ## teste proxy
    ProxyPass "/api" "http://api.mydomain.com.br"
    ProxyPassReverse "/api" "http://api.mydomain.com.br"

    ProxyPass / http://cliente.mydomain.com.br
    ProxyPassReverse / http://cliente.mydomain.com.br


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        # RewriteEngine on
        # RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.api.mydomain.com.br [OR]
        # RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =api.mydomain.com.br
        # RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

I commented on the Header because it always gives an error, apparently due to having a duplicate Header configuration.
How to solve this? Please.
